# Compile error using nested generics and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, nested-generics

I can't figure out a solution to my problem. In both of these cases I get a compile error. Any help to make it work?

Case 1:

```
public class Entity<T extends EntityHandler<Entity>> {

    protected T handler;

    public void remove() {
        for (Entity entity : handler.getEntities()) {
            // do stuff
        }

        handler.saveEntity(this);
    }
}

public class Player<T extends PlayerHandler<Player>> extends Entity</*error here*/T> {}

public class EntityHandler<T extends Entity> {

    private List<T> entities;

    public void saveEntity(T entity) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public List<T> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }
}

public class PlayerHandler<T extends Player> extends EntityHandler<T> {}
```

Error: type argument T is not within bounds of type-variable T

Case 2:

```
public class Entity<T extends EntityHandler<? extends Entity>> {

    protected T handler;

    public void remove() {
        for (Entity entity : handler.getEntities()) {
            // do stuff
        }

        handler.saveEntity(/*error here*/this);
    }
}

public class Player<T extends PlayerHandler<? extends Player>> extends Entity<T> {}

public class EntityHandler<T extends Entity> {

    private List<T> entities;

    public void saveEntity(T entity) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public List<T> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }
}

public class PlayerHandler<T extends Player> extends EntityHandler<T> {}
```

Error: incompatible types: Entity cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Entity

Question: why does the enhanced for loop compile and it doesn't throw a compile error similar to the one above?

Comment: Would you consider make EntityHandler not generic? but and abstract that has a setter for Entity?

Comment: public class Player<T extends PlayerHandler<Player>> extends Entity<T> is really constrained in the way you can shift things around

Answer (score 2):

In first case you've marked error in wrong place. It's here:

```
public class Player<T extends PlayerHandler<Player>> extends Entity<T //here> {}
```

> Error:(20, 73) java: type argument T is not within bounds of type-variable T

And it's quite easy - `Entity` can be parameterized only with classes which extend `EntityHandler`.

In second case your `for` compiles because of [erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), so basically `getEntities` returns just List of something.

As for `saveEntity` error, there you are trying to pass `capture<? extends Entity` but method expects to have `Entity<T>`, which is not allowed.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but what I wanted was a solution to make my code work with no errors.

Comment: In theory the first T extends PlayerHandler which extends EntityHandler. This should suffice for Entity (20, 73 error). Maybe the compiler assumes that PlayerHandler<Player> does not meet that criteria

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what I have to change in the code. I marked the error in the right place, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in case 1 to

```
public class Entity<T extends EntityHandler<Entity>> {

protected T handler;

public void remove() {
    for (Entity entity : handler.getEntities()) {
        // do stuff
    }

    handler.saveEntity(this);
}
}


public class EntityHandler<T extends Entity> {

private List<T> entities;

public void saveEntity(T entity) {
    // do stuff
}

public List<T> getEntities() {
    return entities;
}
}

public class PlayerHandler<T extends Player> extends EntityHandler</*error here*/T> {}

public class Player<T extends PlayerHandler<?>> extends Entity<EntityHandler<Entity>>{}
```

and I get no compiler error or warning.
Working in Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2 and JavaSE-1.7.

Comment: That's not a valid solution. The T in the Player class would make no sense because the handler will be an EntityHandler and I need a PlayerHandler.

Comment: Ok, next try: 'public class PlayerHandler<T extends Player> extends EntityHandler<Entity<EntityHandler<Entity>>> public class Player<T extends PlayerHandler<?>> extends PlayerHandler<Player<PlayerHandler<Player>>>{}' that would make the handler a Playerhandler

Comment: 'public class PlayerHandler<T extends Player> extends EntityHandler<Entity> public class Player<T extends PlayerHandler<?>> extends PlayerHandler<Player>{}'. Sorry I didn't cleaned it up in the above comment.

Comment: That is even worse. You are extending PlayerHandler to Player (Player should extend Entity) and I need to pass the T to the super class.